# Python : How to create mysql databases with PyMySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

I am using python `3.6`, and I use `PyMySQL` to connect mysql.

I will create several databases. I want to write a Python script to do this for easily creating and removing them.

There is an example in PyMySQL docs with a piece of code like this:
PyMySQL docs ：https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='user',
                             password='passwd',
                             db='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

In the code above, the database already exists.

Now there are no databases in mysql. I want to create them via python and PyMySQL. What should I do?

Answer (score 16):

Just leave out db:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                       user='user',
                       password='passwd')
```

Then get a cursor and create a database:

```
conn.cursor().execute('create database dbname')
```

Create a table in the new database:

```
conn.cursor().execute('create table dbname.tablename (...)')
```

Comment: You also must add this line.

`connection.select_db(DB_NAME)`